# How to use lua plugins in ingress-nginx controller?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, lua, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I am trying to run the Lua plugin on ingress-nginx. I am able to do the below steps using documentaion. however, I have some challenges yet.

Steps on K8s

```
1. Rename the auth.lua to main.lua

2. Create configMap auth-lua using the file  above.
k create configmap auth-lua --from-file main.lua -n ingress-nginx

3. Mount the configmap as folder inside ingress-nginx deployment
..
 ...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: auth-lua
          configMap:
            name: auth-lua
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - ...
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-lua
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/lua/plugins/auth-lua

4. Update the ingress-nginx confimap to include this plugin
data:
  plugins: auth-lua

5. Rollout restart the ingress-nginx deployment.
```

Now, My question is. is my all requests go to plugins or is there any way that I need to mention in ingress-resource to use this plugin?
I want to use this plugin only for some ingress resource. and how can I achieve this?